# Setting vector as a general parameter

Tags: c++, vector, c++14

So I've been trying to create a function that will receive vector objects as a general type in C++. 
I have three classes Coffee, Snack, and Juice. And I have a binary search function to search for a specific item in each of the three vector objects created by those classes. But in order to do the binary search, I'd have to define three binary search functions. For example, binarySearchCoffee(vector coffeeList), binarySearchSnack(vector coffeeList) and the same for the Juice. So, is there a way to create a general vector type parameter that will take in whatever I inserted or is defining three functions ordinary? But I do not think so because it violates the DRY rule. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Make the function templated?

Comment: A vector of one type cannot hold elements of a different type.

Comment: Actually binary search is already available as `std::lower_bound`

Comment: @6502 It's a bit verbose though so not unreasonable to wrap it tbh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what templates are for. Indeed, that's how the vector itself works!!

```
template <typename ElementType>
bool DoMyBinarySearch(const std::vector<ElementType>& container, const ElementType& value)
{
   auto it = std::lower_bound(std::begin(container), std::end(container), value);
   return it != std::end(container) && *it == value;
}
```

You might even consider making the *container* type the template argument, so that you're not restricted to vectors (though that may not be useful in this case).

This example also doesn't consider alternative allocators, or alternative comparators, which may or may not matter to you. [cppreference.com's `std::lower_bound` article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) has a more robust example.

Don't forget to document the precondition that `container` must be sorted.

Comment: Thank you! You just completed a small C++ system for my assignment